# CSS changes are not reflected on mobile devices

Tags: css, ios, iphone, mobile

I am really struggling to get my css for mobile working. On laptop and ipad everything works fine, but on a Iphone I can't seem to get this working.

One of the examples is the logo, which I told to be smaller on mobile via:

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 48.0625em)
.table-first {
    width: 100px;
    flex: 0 0 100px;
}
.table-first {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 75px;
    flex: 0 0 75px;
    max-width: 100px!important;
    display: block;
}
```

I have tried all @media options min-width, min-device-width, max-width etc. It simply is not changing. What I am trying to achieve is the search bar making this smaller and get the icons on the screen as well. Any CSS change is simply not reflecting on the mobile phone.

The following code is added to head html:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your code after the media query condition:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 48.0625em) {
    .table-first {
        width: 100px;
        flex: 0 0 100px;
    }
    .table-first {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 75px;
        flex: 0 0 75px;
        max-width: 100px!important;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Also, it's better to replace your `min-width: 48.0625em` with some pixel value

Comment: This makes both apply, having the first 100px to be leading and having no effect on the mobile css.

Comment: @T.H. you should ask a question correctly next time. You said `I have tried all @media options min-width, min-device-width, max-width etc. It simply is not changing` - there is a solution to why it was not affecting your layout, you need to wrap your code with media query conditions so it will work. Obviously, you should set the needed media query and set CSS that should be changed for this media query.

Comment: sorry quite new to this, but thanks for your help. It did resolve my issue by changing the order of the css. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> change the Max-width **em to px** and **wrap the second table to first**

**Or use this code:**

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px)
    .table-first {
        width: 100px;
        flex: 0 0 100px;
    }
    .table-first {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 75px;
        flex: 0 0 75px;
        max-width: 100px!important;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried the code but max-width is not recognized/loaded when I inspect the element on a desktop. Is this right or is it simply not shown because it is not applicable?